# Binary bomb - phase 2

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering

Hey I am working on defusing a binary bomb and am at phase 2 now and trying to figure out how the defuse should happen. I have added comments about what i think is actually happening in this but correct me if I am wrong and help me understand how this works. This is the phase_2:

```
08048763 <phase_2>:
 8048763:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048764:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048766:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
 ; read 6 numbers
 8048769:   8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 804876c:   83 c0 14                add    $0x14,%eax
 804876f:   50                      push   %eax
 8048770:   8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 8048773:   83 c0 10                add    $0x10,%eax
 8048776:   50                      push   %eax
 8048777:   8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 804877a:   83 c0 0c                add    $0xc,%eax
 804877d:   50                      push   %eax
 804877e:   8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 8048781:   83 c0 08                add    $0x8,%eax
 8048784:   50                      push   %eax
 8048785:   8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 8048788:   83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 804878b:   50                      push   %eax
 804878c:   8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 804878f:   50                      push   %eax
 8048790:   68 18 94 04 08          push   $0x8049418
 8048795:   ff 75 08                pushl  0x8(%ebp)

 ; call scanf()
 8048798:   e8 53 fd ff ff          call   80484f0 <sscanf@plt>
 804879d:   83 c4 20                add    $0x20,%esp
 ; check if first number is greater than 5
 80487a0:   83 f8 05                cmp    $0x5,%eax
 80487a3:   7f 05                   jg     80487aa <phase_2+0x47>
 80487a5:   e8 ad fe ff ff          call   8048657 <explode>
 80487aa:   8b 45 dc                mov    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
 ; check if the 2nd number is 9 ; jump if equals
 80487ad:   83 f8 09                cmp    $0x9,%eax
 80487b0:   74 05                   je     80487b7 <phase_2+0x54>
 80487b2:   e8 a0 fe ff ff          call   8048657 <explode>
 80487b7:   c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)

 ; BEGIN LOOP 
 80487be:   eb 22                   jmp    80487e2 <phase_2+0x7f>
 80487c0:   8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80487c3:   8b 54 85 dc             mov    -0x24(%ebp,%eax,4),%edx
 80487c7:   8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80487ca:   83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
 80487cd:   8b 44 85 dc             mov    -0x24(%ebp,%eax,4),%eax
 ; what is it that gets multiplied here?
 80487d1:   0f af 45 f4             imul   -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 ; compare eax with edx but not clear what happens here. jump when equals
 80487d5:   39 c2                   cmp    %eax,%edx
 80487d7:   74 05                   je     80487de <phase_2+0x7b>
 80487d9:   e8 79 fe ff ff          call   8048657 <explode>
 ; we add 1 before comparing with 5?
 80487de:   83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
 ; compare jump next if number <= 5
 80487e2:   83 7d f4 05             cmpl   $0x5,-0xc(%ebp)
 80487e6:   7e d8                   jle    80487c0 <phase_2+0x5d>
 80487e8:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 80487eb:   68 2a 94 04 08          push   $0x804942a
 80487f0:   e8 16 fe ff ff          call   804860b <say>
 80487f5:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 80487f8:   c9                      leave  
 80487f9:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: `eax` is multiplied by `[ebp-0xC]` (= the value at memory address `ebp-0xC`) and compared against `edx`, and if they are not the same, the bomb explodes. Further down, the loop counter is incremented and then compared against 5 - the loop continues until the value reached 6 after incrementing (`jle` is used so it's checking basically if `++i <= 5` in C terms)

Comment: This has been solved, never mind.

Comment: Then please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It enters the loop and multiplies sfirst number with 1 to produce 2nd number, second number with 2, to produce 3rd number and so on until 6 numbers have been reached. So it turns out like this - 9 9 18 54 216 1080 And I added some comments as well:

```
08048763 <phase_2>:
 ; set up stack frame
 8048763:   55                      push   ebp
 8048764:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 8048766:   83 ec 28                sub    esp,0x28

 ; prepare memory 6 numbers
 8048769:   8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
 804876c:   83 c0 14                add    eax,0x14
 804876f:   50                      push   eax
 8048770:   8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
 8048773:   83 c0 10                add    eax,0x10
 8048776:   50                      push   eax
 8048777:   8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
 804877a:   83 c0 0c                add    eax,0xc
 804877d:   50                      push   eax
 804877e:   8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
 8048781:   83 c0 08                add    eax,0x8
 8048784:   50                      push   eax
 8048785:   8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
 8048788:   83 c0 04                add    eax,0x4
 804878b:   50                      push   eax
 804878c:   8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
 804878f:   50                      push   eax
 8048790:   68 18 94 04 08          push   0x8049418
 8048795:   ff 75 08                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]

 ; call scanf()
 8048798:   e8 53 fd ff ff          call   80484f0 <sscanf@plt>
 804879d:   83 c4 20                add    esp,0x20

 ; check if there are more than 5 arguments, if not - explode
 80487a0:   83 f8 05                cmp    eax,0x5
 80487a3:   7f 05                   jg     80487aa <phase_2+0x47>
 80487a5:   e8 ad fe ff ff          call   8048657 <explode>
 80487aa:   8b 45 dc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24]

 ; check if the 1st number is 9, if it is, goto 80487b7, else explode
 80487ad:   83 f8 09                cmp    eax,0x9
 80487b0:   74 05                   je     80487b7 <phase_2+0x54>
 80487b2:   e8 a0 fe ff ff          call   8048657 <explode>

 ; BEGINNING OF LOOP for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
 80487b7:   c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x1 
 80487be:   eb 22                   jmp    80487e2 <phase_2+0x7f>

 ; Get loop counter ,store in EDX
 80487c0:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
 80487c3:   8b 54 85 dc             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+eax*4-0x24]

 ; again take loop counter minus 1 to EAX
 80487c7:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
 80487ca:   83 e8 01                sub    eax,0x1
 80487cd:   8b 44 85 dc             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+eax*4-0x24]

 ; multiply our number with loop counter minus 1
 80487d1:   0f af 45 f4             imul   eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]

 ; compare number with expected value, goto 80487de if equals
 80487d5:   39 c2                   cmp    edx,eax
 80487d7:   74 05                   je     80487de <phase_2+0x7b>
 80487d9:   e8 79 fe ff ff          call   8048657 <explode>

 ; increase loop counter
 80487de:   83 45 f4 01             add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x1

 ; compare loop counter to 5, jump to start if less that or equal
 80487e2:   83 7d f4 05             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x5
 80487e6:   7e d8                   jle    80487c0 <phase_2+0x5d>
 80487e8:   83 ec 0c                sub    esp,0xc

 ; Push defuse message and call "say", leave and return
 80487eb:   68 2a 94 04 08          push   0x804942a
 80487f0:   e8 16 fe ff ff          call   804860b <say>
 80487f5:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 80487f8:   c9                      leave  
 80487f9:   c3                      ret
```